# Rewrite or replace data sent using res.write before res.send() or res.end()

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I recently observed that on triggering a `response.write('<some text>')` multiple times before a `response.send()` or `response.end()` is called, the text which is sent in forthcoming `response.write`s just gets added on to what was sent before, until the `send` or `end` is triggered.

For example:

```
.on('data', data => {
    res.write('started ');
})
.on('progress', progress => {
    res.write('progress ');
})
.on('end', end => {
    res.end('finished');
})
```

Corresponding response I receive in the `request.responseText` is something like

> started progress progress progress progress....[AND SO ON]....progress progress finished.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to just rewrite the data rather than the usual appending which we're seeing here.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds exactly like the job of res.end or res.send. You should be restructuring your code to handle the response better. Probably it will help if you can expound more on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @suv... You're right actually.. But then, when I do a res.send/end in place of the write, it throws an error saying "can't set headers once they're sent."

Comment: res.send and res.end close the tcp connection since the response has been sent. You can only send one response to one request. Trying to do another res.send/end after the first one is not valid, so yeah, you can't set a header/data because the response is already dispatched. You should restructure your code to handle the response better.

Comment: So what do you think would be a good way to do it if I need to keep sending some data, something like progress status maybe from the node api to my angular controller every now and then before ending the response?

Comment: You have multiple ways. Your client can poll the server for data, server can push the data over websockets or using server sent events.